# How can I access widgets from a customized widget?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlineedit

How can I access widgets from a customized widget?

For example:

I have a customized widget:
[image]

Now I have a "user info" form that has a QWidget promoted to "My Custom Widget":

[image]

How can I get the text from my custom widget? (e.g. `QLineEdit->text()`)

Comment: This question is too broad as it stands.  It all depends on how you created your widget.  Did you compile a UI description with `uic`?  If so, you should have an object with pointers to all the relevant child objects of the UI.  If you created it "by hand", you'll have to manage your own pointers.  Show us a [mcve] of some code that works like yours, and this question may become answerable.

Comment: If I infer correctly from your use of the word "promoted", you're creating a UI file with Qt Designer.  So you should be able to simply use the methods you wrote in your custom widget to access those fields.

Comment: In fact, it was not me who created these widgets, but I need to access them. I think they were created "by hand". I believe I'll have to create signals and slots to set and get the values of these fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers, I created some getters and setters methods to get and set the values of the fields in the "**My Custom Widget**".

In my **MyCustomWidget** class I created the **getters** and **setters** for each field:

```
public:
    void setNameLineEdit(QString value);
    QString getNameLineEdit();

    void setAddressLineEdit(QString value);
    QString getAddressLineEdit();

    void setPhoneLineEdit(QString value);
    QString getPhoneLineEdit();
```

And then:

```
void MyCustomWidget::setNameLineEdit(QString value)
{
    ui->nameLineEdit->setText(value);
}

QString MyCustomWidget::getNameLineEdit()
{
    return ui->nameLineEdit->text();
}

...
```

Now I can access these methods from my **UserInfo** class:

```
ui->myCustomWidget->setNameLineEdit( QString("Paul") );
```

Thanks a lot for all help.

Answer (score 2):

The right way is to create a suitable accessor method in your `MyCustomWidget` implementation:

```
namespace Ui {
    class MyCustomWidget;
}

class MyCustomWidget : public QWidget
{
    // You may also wish to add WRITE and NOTIFY methods;
    // that's left as an exercise for the reader.
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name)

    const std::unique_ptr<Ui::MyCustomWidget> ui;

public:
    explicit MyCustomWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyCustomWidget();

    QString name() const;
};
```

```
#include "ui_mycustomwidget.h"

// Constructor and destructor
MyCustomWidget::MyCustomWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyCustomWidget)
{}

MyCustomWidget::~MyCustomWidget() = default;

// Accessor
QString MyCustomWidget::name() const
{
    return ui->nameEdit->text();
}
```

You can then call the `MyCustomWidget::name()` method from within methods of `UserInfo` in the normal way:

```
ui->customWidget->name();
```

You'll want to create similar accessors for `address()` and `phone()` too, of course.

---

The hacky way would be to obtain the line-edit by name, using `QObject::findChild<QLineEdit>()`.  That really breaks encapsulation, and I won't describe that further.

Comment: Actually, I did this "hacky way" using the command `findChild` and it worked, but I don't think this is a good way to do so. I will try to create a suitable accessor method like you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`QLineEdit->text()` is syntactically incorrect and won't compile. `QLineEdit::text()` will not compile either, because `text()` is non-static member and this call does not make sense without a `QLineEdit` object.

Back to your question, first you need to access a custom widget itself. It's easy, once you named the widget somehow in the editor:

[image]

In this example its name is `customWidget`. Thus, in the `ui` private member of `QDialog` class you'll find a public member named `customWidget`, which has type `MyCustomWidget` and corresponds to a widget on the picture. Having this, you may access the public members of `customWidget`. `QDialog` corresponds to your User Info widget class.

For example, you may declare signals (let's call them `value1Changed(QString)`, `value2Changed(QString)` and so on) in `MyCustomWidget` and forward signals from `QLineEdit`s to these signals using signal-to-signal `connect()`. Then you may connect `value1Changed` to any slot of `QDialog` or any other object from the scope where `customWidget` pointer is visible.

Another way to go is to declare public methods like `QString getLine1Content() const` in `MyCustomWidget` and access them from `QDialog` whenever you want.

These are not the only methods to access members of a custom widget, but the most frequently used ones.

Comment: The `QLineEdit->text()` command is just an example to show that I want to get the text of each **QLineEdit** object.
Thanks for your answer. I actually thought about doing it, but I think I'll try the example of @TobySpeight first.